# Draw regression in a hexbinplot

Tags: r, plot, regression

hexbin already has an option to create a regression line, which is `type="r"`.

Unfortunately, it seems like you can't make the regression line thicker or change the color, that's why you can't see the line well. That's why I have to create one myself.

My question is, how I can plot a selfmade regression line with hexbinplot, so it lays at the same place like the regression line of hexbinplot, which I get with type="r"?

```
library(hexbin)

    hexbinplot(TS.GW.fieldmean.zoo$GW.2~TS.MW.fldmean.1000.zoo$MW.fldm.2, main = "Scatterplot: Tägliches Mittel",
               xlab="name1 [m/s]",ylab="name2 [m/s]",style="nested.centroids", type="r")
    hbin <- hexbin(TS.GW.fieldmean.zoo$GW.2,TS.MW.fldmean.1000.zoo$MW.fldm.2)
    hvp <- hexViewport(hbin)
    reg <- lm(TS.GW.fieldmean.zoo$GW.2~TS.MW.fldmean.1000.zoo$MW.fldm.2)
    hexVP.abline(hvp,reg$coefficients[1], reg$coefficients[2], col = "red", lty = 1, lwd = 2)
```

Here is the plot of the selfmade regression line in red and the black line, I get while using type="r":

[image]

Comment: We focus on questions and answers here, not chit chat, so some effort is made to remove such things from questions. It is standard practice to _remove_ things like "Thanks in advance", greetings etc when editing questions here.

Comment: Didn't know, that this is already chit chat. I'm sorry.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I just wanted to make sure you understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself. It's so easy:

```
hexbinplot(yy~xx, main = "(text) Scatterplot: text",
           xlab="wind",ylab="other wind",style="nested.centroids", type=c("r"), col.line = "yourcolor", lwd="3")
```